# checks for spike-in sequence controls

Tags: ngs, illumina, errors, spike-in

I would like to know what do people verify when designing/using spike-in controls, to be used in sequencing experiments (mainly Illumina). So far I came up with this list:

- Does it align only to a given genome synthetic reference?
- Does it contain G-quadruplexes? E.g. [QGRS Mapper](http://bioinformatics.ramapo.edu/QGRS/index.php)
- Does it contain known Illumina error motifs? (Do this matter anymore for recent platforms/chemistries?) See [this article](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-016-0976-y)
- Does it contain other motifs known to be polymerase inhibitors? [Ref](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4923904/)

Anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm a developer for http://www.sequin.xyz.

Sequin is a new set of spiked-in controls for next-generation sequencing, and that includes Illumina. We design controls for RNA-Seq, genome sequencing, metagenomics etc.

Please study our [papers](http://www.sequin.xyz/about/papers/) if you want more details.

- **Reference Standards For Next-Generation Sequencing** by Hardwick should be a good start.

Here's my list:

1. Measured counts against input concentration. Pearson's correlation, spearman correlation and regression slope.
2. PCA analysis
3. Whether the synthetic aligned to the synthetic reference
4. Spiked-in amount (e.g. dilution)
5. Diagnostic statistics
6. ROC Curve
7. Detection limit

(1) is important because the controls should give you correlation = 1, and slope = 1 in a perfect flawless experiment. This is a sample output (you can read more about it in our papers):

[image]

(2) This is our sample PCA (our paper has the details)

[image]

(3) is also important but you can only do that in simulations.

(5)

[image]

(6)

[image]

(7)

[image]

Comment: Does Anaquin/Sequin allow for the design of new spike-in controls that don't align to a set of references?

Comment: @719016 Sequins assume the spiked-in reads aligned to a synthetic reference.

Comment: Does it allow for the design of new spikeins wrt a new synthetic reference?

Comment: Does it check if the set of synthetic reference is unique against other Genomes and unique against itself?